# Function not being defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, undefined

```
def winheight(height):

    try:
        height = int(raw_input('Enter the height of the window in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter an integer'
        winheight(height)

    winlength(length)

def winlength(length):

    try:
        length = int(raw_input('Enter the length of the window in metres: '))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter an integer'
        winlength(length)

    pricing(height, length)

def pricing(height, length):

    height_length = height * length

    price = int(height_length) * 100

    total = int(price) + 50

    print int(total)

winheight(height)
```

This is my code, I'm trying, to complete a class task for a window replacement business, for every square meter it costs $100 + an initial $50

However whenever I try to run this code I get the error:

> line 31, in 
>   winheight(height) **NameError:** name 'height' is not defined

I need height and length to be defined globally so I can use them for the final cost, I am unsure how to fix this problem, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code in your question.

Comment: height is not defined, remember variables are scoped in python.

Comment: call `pricing` and `winlength` methods after its definition and after `winheight` call

Comment: Use standard 4-space indents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
def winheight(): #define window-height-getting function
    while True:
        try:
            height = int(raw_input("Enter the height of the window in metres: ")) #get user input for window height
            return height
        except ValueError: #catch improper inputs
            print "Please enter an integer"
def winlength(): #define window-length-getting function
    while True:
        try:
            length = int(raw_input("Enter the length of the window in metres: ")) #get user input for window length
            return length
        except ValueError: #catch improper inputs
            print "Please enter an integer"

def pricing(height, length): #define price-calculating function
    area = height * length #math to determine total price
    price = area * 100
    total = price + 50
    return total

user_height = winheight() #get window height from user
user_length = winlength() #get window length from user

total_price = pricing(user_height, user_length) #calculate total price by passing user window height and length to the pricing function

print "The total price is: $" + str(total_price) #print result
```

Comment: This helps a lot, wasn't exactly sure where or how to place return functions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`height` is really not defined. The `height` variable you define in your function is a *local* variable. It stops existing after the function call ends. You can either return it, or use a global (but rather, don't use globals)

```
 def get_height():
     while True:
        try:      
          height = input()
        except ValueError:
          continue
        else:
          return height
```

and call it from your main script by `height = get_height()` (similarly for `length)` before calling `pricing(height, length)`.

A few other notes:

- to try `input()` again, use a while loop instead of calling the function recursively (because the leaves the previous function stacks open)
- there's no point passing a `height` variable and re-assigning `height = input`. The value passed to height is a copy, so the original does not change.

Comment: I somewhat understand what you're saying but not exactly sure how to implement this in as its my first time using more than one define function, sorry :/

Comment: @HarrisonLalor: just like that. replace the `winheight` function with this one, and  in you main script, use `height = get_height()`

Comment: Okay I get it, I have to get the value from the output of the whole defined 'function' not the variable inside it, appreciate it!

Comment: @HarrisonLalor: a function *returns* something. just like you do `y = f(x)` in math. it doesn't change the `x`, it produces a new value, which you assign to `y`

Comment: Yeah I get you what you're saying, I was just unaware that's how defining worked, makes a lot of sense though, my only prior experience to this is learning python on codecademy